# Security protocol of python Requests

Tags: python, security, python-requests

I would like to know the security protocol used by the "requests" library in Python. Specifically, I would like to understand whether the library implements certain security measures such as string escaping, to ensure safe extraction of website content.

For example, say I'm making a request to some site that executes a questionable js script on the back end. What would happen if I ran the following code?

```
r = requests.get('https://somesite.com')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests will just return a string (and response code and such) with whatever the server replies.  Like the name implies, the requests library sends an HTTP request to a server, which then sends a response.

The only processing it does for the text of the response is to handle encoding - *i.e.*, to handle unicode processing.  And if you want, you can even shut this off.  This is explained in the manual [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content).

For example, this code will just print the HTML source code to the site example.org:

```
r = requests.get('https://example.org/')
print(r.text);
```

If the server *executes* questionable javascript, there is nothing anyone can do about that, because the server does whatever it wants to do when it receives a request.  The server should ideally be programmed not to do this, but it is not really the client's problem.

If the server *returns* questionable javascript, then that javascript will not be escaped.  Python won't execute javascript just because it is in a string, but if you're generating HTML based on the response from requests, then it is up to you to make sure that the HTML you generate doesn't have questionable javascript in it.

Thus, treat responses received from requests as untrusted input unless you trust the server generating them.  You don't need to worry about requests executing code from the server itself, but if the server gives you malicious data and you pass that input over something that *will* execute it, like a web browser if it is javascript, then you might be in trouble.